# Generate AnyCPU assembly for C# with SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig

is it possible to create a AnyCpu assembly with SWIG? I have both the x86 and x64 binaries compiled (c++) and I'm able to generate a SWIG P/Invoke Wrapper. But the wrapper is dependent on the invoked native dll (which is CPU specific). But I like the idea of let the executable decide instead of having two different executables. I'm would put the dlls in seperate folders (e.g. named x64/x86) if this is helpful. Or do I have to write a handmade wrapper in C# which decides to load the right dll?

Thanx for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to roll you own wrapper.

I came across the solution CLRZMQ was using for similar reasons.

They solved it pretty well by embedding both .dll versions and extracting those accoring to the current platform:

They determined the running platform by using  `Environment.Is64BitProcess` and adding a x86 or x64 suffixe + version string before extracting and loading the correct dll.

Here is [their solution to the problem](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/blob/master/src/ZeroMQ/Interop/UnmanagedLibrary.cs) and here is the [corresponding discussion](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/pull/23) which gives different ideas on how to solve it. Also interesting is their [SafeLibraryHandle](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/blob/master/src/ZeroMQ/Interop/SafeLibraryHandle.cs) which I just found out about.